# How can I launch an app automatically using MDM?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, remote-access, mdm

I have implemented an Android Management API and a CustomApp API into my project. As I have full device control `"managementMode": "DEVICE_OWNER"`. Is there is a way to launch the app automatically after applying the policy?

**My policy is:**

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.xxx.kiosk",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "managedConfiguration": {
        "venueId": 8
      }
    },
    {
      "packageName": "com.evernote",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
  ],
  "setupActions": [
    {
      "launchApp": {
        "packageName": "com.xxx.kiosk"
      },
      "title": {
        "defaultMessage": "Hello"
      },
      "description": {
        "defaultMessage": "Testing"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried to implement setupActions -> launchApp -> packageId but nothing happens. The policy only installs the app but does not launch it.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi, I don't think you can combine ```Android Management API``` and have ```"managementMode": "DEVICE_OWNER"```.
Can you explain how you've achieved it ?

Comment: Clarify your question please

Comment: I meant to ask how did you manage to get full control of the device using Android Management API ? Does your app has ```"managementMode": "DEVICE_OWNER"``` ?

Comment: Through QR code -> https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe such functionality is available using the AMAPI for already provisioned devices.

The `setupActions` were meant to be executed at provisioning time using the Android Device Policy app. The policy in your example should automatically start the `com.xxx.kiosk` app right after the device gets provisioned.

Comment: I see.. Thanks 